# Convert redirect from .config in htaccess

Tags: xml, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to convert this code in htaccess. I tried some methods but none of them working. Please help me to covert this code to htaccess.

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteRules" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logisticalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />

          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />

        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Do you know what the existing IIS config does? You should describe the requirements in natural language.

Answer (score 0):

The IIS config in the question states that for any request, that does not map to a file and does not map to a directory and the requested URL-path path does not start `/api` then rewrite the request to `/index.html`.

This can be achieved in Apache `.htaccess` using mod_rewrite like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^api /index.html [L]
```

However, it is unusual that `index.html` (a plain HTML source file) would be able to handle such a request out of the box.

This is a reasonably standard "front-controller" pattern, with a single exception.